# php SoapClient, __soapCall and __getLastRequest / __getLastResponse

Tags: php, xml, soap, soap-client

I used a downloaded tool to auto-create a wrapper for a web service (fedex rate service) as it creates a really handy code base for accessing the service that auto-generates a class map and builds an auto-loading data structure by asking the web service itself for it's requirements and capabilities. It creates this wrapper as an 'extend' of `SoapClient` itself.

The only problem is, that it makes the separate service calls using an abstract wrapper that utilizes the `__soapCall` method. The problem that I've noticed with this is that it apparently doesn't populate anything where you can retrieve the XML from the calls themselves. Whenever I call `__getLastRequest` or `__getLastResponse`, they just return null even though `__soapCall('getRates', $args)` returns a php object response from the service.

Short of my re-writing the auto-generated code to call `$this->getRates($args)` or something similar, is there any trick to seeing the XML used in the request and returned in the response when using `__soapCall` ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I thought I had trace defaulted to true, and the reason i was getting back 'null' was that it was defaulting to false.

As long as I create the interface instance with the second argument `array('trace'=>1)` I'm getting the XML now.

Comment: Yeah, just reviewing your question and ***trace*** option popped into my mind as well. Unless it's `TRUE`, those two `__getLastR*` methods return `NULL`. Btw, to which tool do you refer to creating the classes?